# missing imports errors in vscode, python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, importerror

I am creating a program which recognizes speech and tells me if someone calls me, this is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from plyer import notification

#functions list
functions=[]

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    # read the audio data from the default microphone
    audio_data = r.record(source, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing...")
    # convert speech to text
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language="it-IT")
    print(text)

    words=text.lower.split()
    if words.count("gabriele")==1 :
            notification.notify(
                title = "Someone's calling you!!",
                message = 'Answer or he/she will get angry!',
                app_icon = "call_recognizer.jpg",
                timeout = 10,
            )
```

i made it following some guides and tried executing it in pieces and it works perfectly, however when i put it all in vscode it doesn't make me execute it because it gives me two errors in imports something which i don't really understand.
[image]

I've tried reinstalling the packages from the command prompt but it rightly said me that they were installed yet. I've also tried clicking on the vscode link to github which explains errors but it didn't really help. I've also checked my python version and tried reinstalling the packages with the pip3 command instead of just pip as a past post here on stack overflow said but nothing worked.
Did i do something wrong or is it just a problem of my computer?

Comment: So, the VSCode editor allows one to set the python interpreter/environment and that is not necessarily the same as what is the default system python env that might be active in your terminal.  I would verify that  your vscode python iterpreter path is set to what aligns with your default env.